# Delete contents of Source workbook before closed

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have built an excel application(Feedback survey form like), where the user enters the information and then saves and uploads to database. Once the form is completed for a single account and then saved, I need to delete all the cell contents in the source workbook. But when I open the saved file again to check back for later reference, values should be retained instead of clearing when closed.

Any best way I can do this ?. Right now I have included a close button in my form, when clicked will delete the contents of  original workbook. How can I do this task with the default close button of excel ?

```
     Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   On Error GoTo NoBlanks
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").ClearContents
     ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D8").ClearContents
     ActiveSheet.Range("D12:E12").SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
     ActiveSheet.Range("D16:F19").ClearContents
     ActiveSheet.Range("D26:F29").ClearContents
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_upload").Range("D39:D41").ClearContents
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").ClearContents

  NoBlanks:
      Resume Next

    wb.Close (True)
     wb.save


     End Sub
```

Comment: You can make use of the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event. Yet, this event does not always fire (depending on how you close Excel). So, you might want to stick to what you have now.

Comment: Ralph, I have updated my code in the question. This eventually deletes the cell contents of original template when closed. But when i open my saved files, close and reopen them  it deletes the content even from saved  files.

Comment: As mentioned before, the event `Workbook_BeforeClose` is not reliable as it depends on how you are closing the file. The best way to do it would be a button in the file and then press the button to reset the file (and delete all unwanted content). Neither the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event nor the `Workbook_Open` event can be relied upon at all times.